# Insert data in mysql from contact form 7 using wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, contact-form-7

I, trying to insert data from my contact form 7 to mysql using wordpress.

So for that I create a basic contact form:

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
[text* name:sName ] </p>

<p>Your Email (required)<br />
[email* name:sEmail] </p>

<input type="submit" name:submit>
```

This is the php function:

```
<?php 
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
include ('../../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;    
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name=addslashes($_POST['sName']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['sEmail']);
$wpdb->insert("Users",array(
"sName"=>$name,
"sEmail"=>$email,
));
}    
$wpdb->show_errors();
?>
```

And the Page:

```
<form action="/wp-content/plugins/my-codes/insertUser.php" method="post">
[contact-form-7 id="11" title="Contact form 1"]
</form>
```

So far I know that the php function works, and that I have connection to the data base, because if instead of using the contact form 7 I use the following code in the page (see below), it insert the information perfectly

```
<form action="/wp-content/plugins/my-codes/insertUser.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="sName" />
Email: <input type="text" name="sEmail" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

So I know that the problem is coming somewhere from the contact form, but I cant see what Im doing wrong. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You're using the proper database interface. Don't use `addslashes` it will mangle your data.

Comment: Im using latin1_swedish_ci, thats ok?

Comment: You really should be using UTF-8, but that's beside the point. `addslashes` inserts slashes into your data, so names like `"O'Reilly"`  become `"O\\'Reilly"`. This is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Ok, but Im not using **addslashes** Im using an other one. And I think the problem comes from the contact form code, cause if I use a different behaviour I have no problem.

Comment: Your code clearly has `addslashes` in it. If you're not using that code why is it in the question? You also haven't explained your problem very well.

Comment: I am using that code. Buy what Im trying to point is that if I use an other implementation, then it works. So what Im trying to say is that the problem come from the content form. The problem is that im not able to insert the name and the email into de Users table

Comment: "Not able" means what? Do you get an error? You need to do some diagnostics here.

Comment: No error. Nothing. Just not inserting. No line added to the db

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way of doing it:

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br /> </p>
[text* sName id:sName]

<p>Your Email (required)<br /></p>
[email* sEmail id:sEmail] 

<input type="submit" name="submit">
```